# How to Assign Classification class to product In Hybris through impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

How To Assign **Classification class**  to **product** In Hybris through impex

Comment: How to assign the classificationclass to product?

Answer (score 4):

ClassificationClass will be assigned same as Categories to Product since ClassificationClass extends Category only.

**Example :**

```
INSERT_UPDATE ClassificationClass; code[unique = true]; $catalogVersion; name[lang = en]
                                 ; classificationClass;                ; classificationClass

UPDATE Product; code(code)[unique = true]; catalogVersion(catalog(id[default = $catalogName]), version[default = 'Online'])[unique = true] supercategories(code)[mode = append];
; testProduct; ; classificationClass
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped me.

Answer (score 1):

> INSERT_UPDATE
>   Product;code[unique=true];$feature1;$feature2;$feature3;$feature4;$feature6;$feature7;$feature8;$catalogVersion;

You may check **products-classifications.impex** for examples

Comment: INSERT_UPDATE Product;code[unique=true];$feature1;$feature2;$feature3;$feature4;$feature6;$feature7;$feature8;$catalogVersion;                                                                This one is to assign the features to product..  My question is how to assign the classificationclass to product....